# Find out if a transaction has been started in SQLite

Tags: r, sqlite

Is it possible to figure out if a transaction has been started, i.e. a `BEGIN`has be submitted?

There seems to be a C function `sqlite3_get_autocommit()` that does that, but is it also possible to get this information from within R? Maybe some SQL code?

I am trying to get nested transactions to work, where I write an inner function and I don't if there is an outer function which has started a transaction or not.

If in transaction, I would use SAVEPOINT in the inner function, else BEGIN.

Comment: Who else would be sharing your current SQLite connection such that you would even need/want to know the autocommit mode?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Many applications that use RDBMS now-a-days execute database statements in a non-deterministic order, not just a static SQL script.  It's a perfectly valid question without having to justify by "who else would be sharing...", implying that the OP should "just get control of your code..."